# setting mongo serverside date on an insert - Mongo Driver 2.0

Tags: mongodb, insert, mongodb-.net-driver, bulk

I am currently able to use the Typed UpdateDefinitionBuilder to tell the mongo server to set the datetime instead of my code setting it myself.

Is there a way to tell an insert the same thing using the strongly typed interface?

I was hoping for a BsonAttribute for that field

I need to do this for a InsertManyAsync

Thanks in advance

Richard

Comment: Not by insert. You can use [`$currentDate`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/currentDate/) with "upserts", but you seem to be alluding to the fact you are already doing that. For inserts you need to have a `Date` type that will store as BSON Date, and feed it per document to insert.

Comment: Hi Blakes Seve .thanks for the reply.. Not sure I understand. I have the following: `[BsonElement("created")]
        [BsonDateTimeOptions(DateOnly = false, Kind = DateTimeKind.Utc, Representation = BsonType.DateTime)]
        public DateTime Created { get; set; }
` is this what you mean? I think you are saying that I need to create a BsonDocument from my strongly typed class and push it in that way?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to "default" a value in the class instance other than by calling in the constructor. So there is a BSON attribute for a default value, but I think that only applies when "reading" data back and the property is not present in the stored document. So that would not automatically be applied to new instances that have not been "inserted" yet. The operator mentioned before is an atomic update operator which would set the property to the current server time on "update", but of course that is a different method.